# Ruby/Rails - Presenter class class and instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a base presenter that I'm using for mainly JSON and CSV type presenting.  I was posed with an issue that I wasn't sure how to handle.  If I have a PhotoPresenter with a class method I can't access the instance method help so I had to create the self.help method but I think this sucks..any ideas on how to avoid this overlap with instance and class level methods.  Probably just tired and being stupid about it

```
class Presenter
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def self.as_collection(collection)
    collection.collect{|object| self.new(object)}
  end

  def help
    Helper.instance
  end

  def self.help
    Helper.instance
  end

  class Helper
    include Singleton
    include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid some duplication as follows:

```
def self.help
  Helper.instance
end

def help
  self.class.help
end
```